# HTTP 405 on Error on HTTP POST IIS ASP .NET

Tags: asp.net, http, iis

I'm working on a web application that is referenced from another, external application. The external application tries to do a `POST` on the `vdir` when opening. At this point, I get an HTTP 405 Error:

> HTTP Error 405 - The HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.
>   Internet Information Services (IIS)

I checked the IIS event logs and I see that the external application tries to post, but I can't change permissions for a directory, since I need an extension.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Make sure you are including the web page file name in the post URL (http://yoursite/app/Page.aspx instead of http://yoursite/app)
- You may need to explicitly allow POSTs to the file type of your web page.  See [here](http://www.somacon.com/p126.php) for instructions of how to do it in IIS.  (Those instructions are for IIS 6.  For IIS 7 simply go to Handler Mappings, click Edit for the appropriate entry, click the Request Restrictions button, then go to the Verbs tab.)

Comment: This solution worked, so I guess I'll give that to you. My question was a little different though. I was wondering if there is a way to allow a post on the vdir itself. For example, let's say instead of the default.aspx I want to test another page, I would have to change the external link every time...

Comment: To http-post to a directory you can convert the directory to an application (in IIS Manager, right-click the directory and select Convert To Application).  Not sure if there's any better way.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a default document in the virtual directory that you are posting to?  IIS will not allow POST commands to a folder, but it should still map the virtual directory to the default document.  Also try removing the trailing slash.

http://forums.iis.net/t/1171316.aspx