# IIS serve XML and "accept but ignore" POST

Tags: xml, post, iis, https, iis-10

I have a request from a developer to "accept but ignore" POST requests made to an XML file on an IIS server.  It is used for testing something I don't understand.  By default, when I put the XML file in the IIS site root and access it via the browser (GET) I get the response I expect. However, if I run the following command:

`curl --data "test=test" https://server/example.xml`

I get this response:

> 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.
> The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.

He just wants a 200 response even if you send POST data.  I found an [old SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047103/iis-405-http-verb-used-to-access-this-page-is-not-allowed-email) that pointed to [this article](https://www.somacon.com/p126.php), but it is a very old version of IIS and when I tried it it did not help.  I tried adding an XML handler mapping but no matter what I picked for "type" I kept getting other errors (usually ASP.net).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the instructions from [this forum post](https://forums.iis.net/t/1182495.aspx) are working. The trick was adding a "script" map instead of a regular handler.

1. Open IIS Manager and navigate to the level you want to manage.
2. In Features View, on the server, site, or application Home page, double-click Handler Mappings.
3. On the Handler Mappings page, in the Actions pane, click Add Script Map.
4. In the Request path box, type *.xml.
5. In the Executable box, type  %systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll.
6. In the Name box, type a friendly name for the handler mapping.
7. Click OK.